# Error: No uiManager configured on Router

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Everything works fine except after doing meteor update 0.8.3 and came up with that error.
Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Updated meteorite packages and it worked.

Comment: i'm getting the same error but that doesn't fix it for me :(

Comment: @Diskdrive: Make sure you don't have a specific version set in smart.json. If you do, mrt update won't update to the latest version of the package. Removing the specific version number solved this problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me while I tried to use IR v0.7.0 with meteor v0.8.3. I had to downgrade meteor to v0.8.1.2.

I think the same happens if you try to use IR v0.8.2 with meteor v0.8.1.2.